# Shell Script to Check for Status of a informatica workflow

Tags: unix, informatica

We have two Informatica jobs that run in parallel.

One starts at 11.40 CET and it has around 300 Informatica workflows in it out of which one is fact_sales.

The other job runs at 3.40 CET and it has around 115 workflows in it many of which are dependent on fact_sales in term of data consistency.

The problem is fact_sales should finish before certain workflows in process 2 starts for data to be accurate, but this doesnt happen generally.

What we are trying to do is to split the process 2 in such a way that fact_sales dependent workflows run only after the fact_sales has finished.

**Can you provide me a way to go about writing a unix shell script that check the status of this fact_sales and if it successfull then kicks off other dependent workflows and if not then it should send a failure mail.
thanks**

Comment: Are you saying that informatica doesn't support job/script/flow dependencies as a basic function? Good luck.

Comment: it does and i never said it doesnt but the system is such we cant use the functionality

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need to write a custom shell script for this. Most of this is pretty standard/common functionality that can be implemented using Command Task and event waits.

```
**Process1 - runs at 11:50**
....workflow
...
 fact_sales workflow. **Add a command task at the end 
                      **that drops a flag, say, fact_sales_0430.done
...
....workflow..500
```

And all the dependent processes will have an event wait that waits on this .done file. Since there are multiple dependant workflows, make sure none of them deletes the file right away. You can drop this .done file at the end of the day or when the load starts for the next day.

```
workflow1
.....
dependantworkflow1 -- Event wait, waiting on fact_sales_0430.done (do not delete file).
dependantworkflow2 -- Event wait, waiting on fact_sales_0430.done (do not delete file).
someOtherWorkflow
dependantworkflow3 -- Event wait, waiting on fact_sales_0430.done (do not delete file).
....
......
```

Comment: i was all guns for this approach but the fact is the dependencies are huge and the number of workflows we are dealing is say about 200 workflows. the problem seems to be that we have to split up the process 2 according to fact_sales. using command task and event wait  at every dependent workflows doesnt seems to a logical task though it is the safest.

Comment: Understood. In that case, you should probably start building a custom scheduler based on UNIX Cron. You can have tables such as WKF_STATUS, WKF_LOGS and  WKF_DEPENDENCIES. Your script will run as a background process and check for any parent processes that are complete (STATUS="COMPLETE") and submit all the dependant processes that have not yet run (STATUS="NOTRUN"). Takes time, but doable. Take a look at http://www.etl-developer.com/2011/04/workflow-dependency-in-informatica-part-2-load-status-entries/ and see if it helps. Your script would be on similar lines except for the deamon process.

Comment: Considering Sales Fact table load needs to be finished for 20 workflows (in the second set) to start. (just an example number, yours can be different).

Like Rajesh said, create a file on your file system after the first load finishes. 

In the second set of workflows, the dependent ones should have this as a extra dependency in the workflow. Wait for the file to be there, but dont delete it. 

sounds fairly simple to me.

Answer (score 0):

A second approach can be as follows -

You must be running some kind of scheduler for launching these workflows.. since Informatica cant schedule multiple workflows in a set, it can only handle worklet/sessions at that level of dependency mgmt.

From the scheduler, create a dependency across the sales fact load wf and the other dependent workflows..

Answer (score 0):

I think below mentioned script will work for you. Please udpate the parameters.

```
    WAIT_LOOP=1
    while [ ${WAIT_LOOP} -eq 1 ]
    do
        WF_STATUS=`pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv $INFA_INTEGRATION_SERVICE -d $INFA_DOMAIN -uv INFA_USER_NAME -pv INFA_PASSWORD -usd Client -f $FOLDER_NAME $WORKFLOW_NAME(fact_sales) | grep "Workflow run status:" | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1`
            echo ${WF_STATUS} | tee -a $LOG_FILE_NAME
                    case "${WF_STATUS}" in
                            Aborted)
                               WAIT_LOOP=0
                               ;;
                            Disabled)
                               WAIT_LOOP=0
                               ;;
                            Failed)
                               WAIT_LOOP=0
                               ;;
                            Scheduled)
                               WAIT_LOOP=0
                               ;;
                            Stopped)
                               WAIT_LOOP=0
                               ;;
                            Succeeded)
                               WAIT_LOOP=0
                               ;;
                            Suspended)
                               WAIT_LOOP=0
                               ;;
                            Terminated)
                               WAIT_LOOP=0
                               ;;
                            Unscheduled)
                               WAIT_LOOP=0
                               ;;
                    esac
                    if [ ${WAIT_LOOP} -eq 1 ]
                    then
                            sleep $WAIT_SECONDS
                    fi
    done
            if [ ${WF_STATUS} == "Succeeded" ]
            then
                    pmcmd startworkflow -sv $INFA_INTEGRATION_SERVICE -d $INFA_DOMAIN -uv INFA_USER_NAME -pv INFA_PASSWORD -usd Client -f $FOLDER_NAME -paramfile $PARAMETER_FILE $WORKFLOW_NAME(dependent_one) | tee $LOG_FILE_NAME
            else
                    (echo "Please find attached Logs for Run" ; uuencode $LOG_FILE_NAME $LOG_FILE_NAME )| mailx -s "Execution logs" $EMAIL_LIST
                    exit 1
            fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have main challenge - keep dependency between large number of infa workflows.
You have two options-

1. You can use some automated scheduling tool to set the dependency and run them one by one properly. There are many free tool but depending on your comfort/time/cost etc. you should choose. link [here](http://www.findbestopensource.com/tagged/job-scheduler).
2. Secondly  you can create your custom job-scheduler. I did a similar scheduler using UNIX script, oracle table. So here are steps for that -

   - Categorize all your workflows into groups. independent flow should go to group 1 and dependent flows on group 1 goes to group2 and so on.
   - Set your process to pick up one by one from above groups and kick them off. If kick off queue is empty then it should wait. call it loop2.
   - Keep a polling loop that will check status of kicked off flows. If failed, aborted etc. fail the process, mail to user and mark all 'in-queue/dependent' flows to failed. If running keep on polling. If succeeded give control to loop 2.
     -if kick off queue is empty then go to next group only if all workflow in that group succeeded.

This is a bit tricky process but it paid off once you set it up. You can add as many workflows as you want and your maintenance will be much more smoother compared to infa scheduler or infa worklet etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a query from repository database using tables such REP_SESS_LOG and check if the status of the fact sales has succeeded or not. Then only you can proceed with the second job.